# CMake: Can I set "local" properties for a subdirectory from the parent project?

Tags: cmake

From my main project I include other external projects or libraries with `add_subdirectory()`. Sometimes I find that I want to set or modify some variables or properties of the child projects thus included, for example:

I want to modify a default option in the subdirectory, without affecting the parent project. If just use `set()` before `add_subdirectory()`, that will create another variable in the parent project that I don't need, and may cause a conflict if there is a variable or option with same name in the parent project.

I want to issue some `add_definitions()` or `include_directories()` for the child project. I can use `target_compile_definitions()` and `target_include_directories()`, but that requires knowing all the targets in the child project.

So, is there a way for passing this information, without modifying the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the subdirectory?

Comment: No, there is not. If you want to set properties in the scope of the subdirectory, you must do it in the subdirectory

Comment: I thought external projects are added with `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found a solution since then?

Comment: @lrineau No, the best I could do was setting subdirectory-specific variables as INTERNAL before calling `add_subdirectory`, so they wouldn't be visible in the GUI at least.